# Simple data populate data with Kendo UI

Tags: input, kendo-ui, field, datasource, populate

Hello I'm quite new to Kendo UI so my question is probably simple as well.
I am working with datasource of Kendo UI (Javascript) that reads a simple JSON object from a remote source, what works fine. 
I struggle now with populating the data into single text fields within the HTML page. I find some example on Kendo UI documention talking about "template", "model", "columns", "binding", etc. but there is nothing I think I can adapt it to my needs. All examples I find are focussed on Kendo Widgets or "grid", what is not what I want.

Example: 
I read the JSON by "datasource" object from remote source, looking like this: 
[{"productid":"30","title":"apple"}]

In my HTML there are two input fields, one with ID="productid" and another one with ID="title"

I don't need a precise code solution just a hint/link how to proceed to populate the JSON elements into the value attributes of the two input fields. If this is possible is there also the other way possible like storing the values of the input fields back to a datasource and send it back to remote server for saving/updating purposes?

Any hint is welcome!

Comment: Have you looked at the MVVM samples?  In particular, http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/remote-binding, looks like it does what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks and yes I did. Imho Teleriks documentation is quite poor and does most often not explain in detail. I'm looking now for a book about Telerik.